# How to write a route who accepts parameters from a model and custom parameters

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I want to write a route that accepts this kind of url:

```
controller\:id\action\:param1\:param2
```

The route should be mixed. Should accept a Model from Doctrine with primary key id but should accept 2 custom parameters too: param1 and param2

How can I achieve this in Symfony 1.4 ?

Comment: What the difference with your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788643/sfdoctrineroutecollection-route-with-extra-parameter

Comment: In the other question I wanted to use the sfDoctrineCollection class. In this question. not. But it seems that nobody knows the answer :-(